# How to get MAX and MIN of two column in laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, max

I have table like in the image, a product with many prices and sales. I want to get max price for that product. If I used `select(\DB::raw("max('price') as price"), 'products.*')` that will return `800` which is wrong, because it has sale with `500` so I need to return `750`. How Can I do this using `laravel`?
any ideas!?

[image]

Comment: Can you use raw SQL?

Comment: Please post the full CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables. A screenshot of phpMyAdmin is not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ex: Products has many relationship product_detail
pls try

```
select(\DB::raw("MAX(IF(product_detail.sale_price > 0, product_detail.sale_price, product_detail.price)) AS 'max'"))
```